# Declaring global variables with a function in python

Tags: javascript, python, global-variables

This piece of JavaScript code works well. My issue isn't with fixing the code itself, rather how I can mimic this in Python.

```
function setupSomeGlobals() {
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 666;
    // Store some references to functions as global variables
    gAlertNumber = function() { alert(num); }
    gIncreaseNumber = function() { num++; }
    gSetNumber = function(x) { num = x; }
}
```

When `setupSomeGlobals()` is called it declares new functions to be used globally. Could this be mimicked in python somehow? I can't figure out how. Python functions don't really seem to run like JavaScript ones, since anything global needs to be returned somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard disclaimer of **do not do this in real code**, a Python (3) translation of your Javascript would be the following:

```
def setup_some_globals():
    # Local variable
    num = 666

    # You have to explicitly declare variables to be global, 
    # otherwise they are local.
    global alert_number, increase_number, set_number

    def alert_number():
        # You can read a variable from an enclosing scope 
        # without doing anything special
        print(num)

    def increase_number():
        # But if you want to assign to it, you need to be explicit about 
        # it. `nonlocal` means "in an enclosing scope, but not 
        # global".
        nonlocal num
        num += 1

    def set_number(x):
        # Same as above
        nonlocal num
        num = x

# Usage:
>>> setup_some_globals()
>>> set_number(3)
>>> increase_number()
>>> alert_number()
4
```

[Docs for `nonlocal` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)

[Docs for `global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

But if you are actually doing this then there's almost certainly a much better way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to create a separate file with functions you want
   to use globally.
2. import this file in any other python file and you should be good to go.

Is there a specific reason you want to mimic the exact functionality? If not this should suffice.

Comment: I suppose my question was asked more to explore the bounds of Python functions. I know that you could simply import globals in other ways. Is there a way to make/import functions after a certain event?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is the worst possible implementation ;) , but I was trying to entertain other possibility, which is somewhat closer to the javascript code in the question.

File 1 : setup_some_globals.py

```
num = 666

def g_alert_number():
    global num
    print num


def g_increase_number():
    global num
    num += 1


def g_set_number(x):
    global num
    num = x
```

the variable num has scope of the module in which it's defined.

File 2 : use_some.py

```
def use_global_functions():
    from setup_some_globals import g_alert_number, g_increase_number, g_set_number
    global g_alert_number
    g_alert_number = g_alert_number
    global g_increase_number
    g_increase_number = g_increase_number
    global g_set_number
    g_set_number = g_set_number


use_global_functions()
g_alert_number()
g_increase_number()
g_alert_number()
g_set_number(99)
g_alert_number()
```

You cannot access the functions, unless and until you call 'use_global_functions()'